# 14.04: Unlocking the screen after sleep logs user off and back on

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen, session

This happened to me just now. I opened my laptop, and got the unlock screen. I entered my password and then it asked me for the password again (it didn't say the password was incorrect, it just asked me again). I think what happened is that after the first password my user was logged off instantly, because after typing my password again I am logged in to my user in a new session.

Are there any logs I can provide to explain this?

Comment: I don't know if this helps but this is a third problem with my new setup on this laptop (two other problems I started as different questions). It seems to me that my setup might not be perfect, maybe it helps.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but it's impossible for me to work like this. I am logged off like this sometimes and I have to re-open my work. I'm going back to Windows and I will install this under VM to see if it can be reproduced. I'll leave this open in case someone else is going through the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a bug for this - astoundingly - so I've submitted one. Bug # 1454698

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1454698

Comment: This is not an answer. You can post comments to the question instead.